# How to specify custom host for connection in RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq, elixir, phoenix-framework

How can I specify my custom host in **send.exs** file if my app which has **receive.exs** is hosted somewhere? I have one elixir app with **send.exs** and another app with **receive.exs** which is Phoenix app and is hosted.

*send.exs*

```
{:ok, connection} = AMQP.Connection.open
{:ok, channel} = AMQP.Channel.open(connection)
AMQP.Queue.declare(channel, "hello")
AMQP.Basic.publish(channel, "", "hello", msg)
IO.puts " [x] Sent everything"
AMQP.Connection.close(connection)
```

*receive.exs*

```
...
{:ok, connection} = AMQP.Connection.open
{:ok, channel} = AMQP.Channel.open(connection)
AMQP.Queue.declare(channel, "hello")
AMQP.Basic.consume(channel, "hello", nil, no_ack: true)
IO.puts " [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C, CTRL+C"
...
```

Comment: Did my answer help at all? Or was something else the solution?

Comment: It helped a lot. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few different forms of `Connection.open`.

[The first](https://github.com/pma/amqp/blob/master/lib/amqp/connection.ex#L71), which you're using, takes no arguments, and uses some default settings (localhost, "guest" username, "guest" password, etc.).

[The second](https://github.com/pma/amqp/blob/master/lib/amqp/connection.ex#L73) takes a Keyword list of options, including host, port, virtual_host, and others. You may use `Connection.open(host: your_host)`. Any settings which you don't provide will use the default setting.

[The third](https://github.com/pma/amqp/blob/master/lib/amqp/connection.ex#L94) form takes a well-formed [RabbitMQ URI](https://www.rabbitmq.com/uri-spec.html) as a String, which is formed using a combination of host, port, username, password, and virtual host. Note that some of these values are optional in the URI.